# Android Market list apps by package name

Tags: android, google-play

Its possible list apps by the package name it uses?

**Example:**

```
com.google.earth
com.google.android.apps.giant
```

And get a list with only two apps?

**EDIT:**
I want open google play store app in my device and search apps by multiples packages name.

[image]

Imagine this picture but with other apps... exactly the app with package name "com.google.earth" and "com.google.android.apps.giant"

Comment: But how do you choose which two?

Comment: Look this picture: [link](http://cdn.webcazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/play_store_facebook_app_20130512.jpg?f73920) I want get this list but not for the query "facebook" instead "com.google.earth, com.goo...."

Comment: Are you asking how to write a program to do this?  Or you want to be able to do this as a user?

Comment: I want create an Intent with this list of packages

Comment: You'll need to use [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class and then iterate over installed packages.  Start writing your code, then post back when you encounter specific issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails), there is no way to achieve this.
You can only open a single app detail page:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

the list of app from a developer:

```
market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>
```

Or a search query

```
market://search?q=<seach_query>&c=apps
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do so. You can use the PackageManager as follows, which will grab all of the installed apps and put them in a List. Then, you can grab the two apps that you want from that List and store them in another list.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

You can iterate over the List as follows:

```
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) { ... }
```

In that loop, you can:

1. Get the installed package name:

   `packageInfo.packageName`
2. Get the source directory:

   `packageInfo.sourceDir`
3. Launch the Activity:

   `pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)`